# Updating a record using Linq-to-SQL

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I do my query...

```
var result = from u in tdc.tblUsers
             where u.UserID == userID
             select u;
```

and then I change the values I want to:

```
foreach (tblUsers u in result)
{
     //change values (and no im not changing the primary key or foreign keys)
}
```

then I submit changes

```
tdc.SubmitChanges();
```

When it hits submit changes, it throws exception that the row wasn't found or was changed. I am the only person using this so there's no other conflicts with accessing the db or locking. Why would it throw the `ChangeConflictException`? I have stepped through with debugger and the data persists all the way through the process, including the changes that I'm trying to make.

I have also tried it this way before and got the same error

```
tblUsers result = (from u in tdc.tblUsers
                   where u.UserID == userID
                   select u).Single();
result.Address = address;
result.Phone = phone;
tdc.SubmitChanges();
```

It will only ever retrieve 1 record with this query since `UserID` is the primary key.

I've done this many times and it has worked. Every example I've found is exactly what I have.

Comment: Are you using the Entity Framework (and if so, what version)?

Comment: Also, do ALL your tables have primary keys. This includes the one you are editing, and any branching tables from foreign keys.

Comment: You are getting this error possibly because one of your fields has something different in the Linq To SQL designer and in the actual database.

Comment: .NET Framework 4 and yes all tables have Primary Keys and proper foreign keys. This query is only going after 1 table, and that table doesnt have any foreign keys in it. It is one of my base tables.

Comment: Any reason you are using `SubmitChanges` instead of `SaveChanges`? Also, what version of the **Entity** framework are you using?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you work with different context? Try to encapsulate it by using

```
using (myContext ctx = new myContext())
{
    var user = ctx.users.first();  
    user.name="blah";
    ctx.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite often, if you look at the actual SQL that Linq-to-SQL generates, you'll see that it is being really over-zealous with matching the database row that you initially retrieved.  Imagine that you have a table with columns ID(PK), A, B, C.  You would think that if you updated column C for a row, it should be sufficient to update the row with a matching primary key.  But what often happens is that Linq-to-SQL is also trying to match on columns A and B as well.  Normally, that's fine.  Unless you have concurrent writes, either from multi-threading or multi-processes, and something else modifies column A or B for the record that you are trying to update.  Then you get these System.Data.Linq.ChangeConflictException: Row not found or changed. errors when you call SubmitChanges() on your data context.